# Google Tag Manager Preview Not working in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, google-tag-manager

I set up the Google tag manager for my application. Added some tags and triggers for testing and those working in Chrome, Mozilla and IE 11. But only the preview mode is not working for IE 11. Once I publish my changes it is reflecting in the application though.

No error in the console, cleared the cache, refreshed and reloaded the application... Still no use. (Third party cookies are accepted for IE 11 and pop-ups are not blocked.) And I checked the source code; GTM Debug Console iframe itself is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more specific how it is not working? The orange banner doesn't show or the preview panel doesn't show up on the site or something else?

From the [doc](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en&ref_topic=9001798):

> When Preview Mode is enabled, the previewed container configuration and debug pane are only visible from the same browser from where you activated Preview Mode.

Besides, make sure you have [enabled the 3rd party cookies](https://www.google.com/search?q=enable%203rd%20party%20cookies%20in%20web%20browser&oq=enable%203rd%20party%20cookies%20in%20web%20browser) and shut down the firewall. You could also try the solutions in [this article](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-preview-mode-not-working/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your browser blocks pop-ups. Sometimes preview won`t open up if browser pop-ups are blocked. Change this setting in your browser and retry